# Can I get I/O information from MPI program

Tags: io, mpi, hpc

Recently, I tried to understand I/O performance tuning. I wanted to get useful I/O information, such as **I/O read/write size, the number of aggregators**, and so on. But I rarely knew about MPI communication. Can I get this information from the MPI program? Or can I get this information from HPC application source code?

Comment: give darshan a try https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/darshan

Comment: Are you using MPI I/O? Even then, information such as the number of aggregators is system specific and you can probably not get it from MPI.

Comment: thank you for your advise. In fact, I'm also using Darshan to collect I/O information, but I think the tracking information belongs to dynamic information. I also hope to get some static information from the code if can @Gilles Gouaillardet

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout I am knowing about I/O stack tuning parameters.And there are some MPI calls in benchmarks. I want to ask for advice that can I get the parameter values of MPI calls (such as MPI_File_read_at) in MPI program by static analysis?